# Change Background color of Active list item in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have  item group list

```
<div id="MainMenu">
    <div class="list-group panel">
        <a href="#why" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Menu 1</a>
        <div class="collapse" id="why">
            <a href="" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Menu 1 a</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Menu 1 b</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Menu 1 c</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Menu 1 d</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Menu 1 e</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Menu 1 f</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#joinus" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Menu 2</a>
        <div class="collapse" id="joinus">
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Menu 2 a</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Menu 2 b</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Menu 2 c</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Menu 2 d</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Menu 2 e</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to change background of active list item, I Know how to change background, but I am unable to get which list is active, or inactive by JavaScript, tried lots of solution given on others but didn't woJrk.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Taqi_Shah/Ltp9qLox/2/)

UPDATE:

Comment: Are you using the 'active' class to make list-group-items active? And are you using jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040820/find-active-tab-using-jquery-and-twitter-bootstrap  - I agree w/ @Peter - usually you always start w/ an `.active` class assigned to one of the tabs/list items, etc. Then when the user switches it, bootstrap automatically changes the `.active` class

Comment: @RobScott Have a look at the `Fiddle` it didn't work as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i does it assign and id to every link in list that is also the page name, and made a js function that is called on body load of the page. the function get the current file name from url and determines which page is this, then by js i made that link class active. this solve my problem. however i share this solution for others to improvement.

```js
function get_current_page() {
  var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split("/");
  var current_page = pathArray[pathArray.length - 1];
  current_page_array = current_page.split(".");
  current_page = current_page_array[0];

  if (
    current_page == "students" ||
    current_page == "my-profile" ||
    current_page == "faqs" ||
    current_page == "forecast-career"
  ) {
    document.getElementById("joinuslist").className += " active";
    document.getElementById("joinus").className += " in";

    if (current_page == "students") {
      document.getElementById("students").className += " active";
    } else if (current_page == "faqs") {
      document.getElementById("faqs").className += " active";
    } else if (current_page == "forecast-career") {
      document.getElementById("forecast-career").className += " active";
    } else if (current_page == "my-profile") {
      document.getElementById("my-profile").className += " active";
    } else {
    }
  } else if (
    current_page == "values" ||
    current_page == "ambassadors" ||
    current_page == "documentary"
  ) {
    if (current_page == "values") {
      document.getElementById("values").className += " active";
    } else if (current_page == "ambassadors") {
      document.getElementById("ambassadors").className += " active";
    } else if (current_page == "documentary") {
      document.getElementById("documentary").className += " active";
    } else {
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.list-group-item.active:hover {
  background-color: #aed248 !important;
  border-color: #aed248 !important;
}
.list-group-item.active,
.list-group-item.active:hover {
  background-color: #007715 !important;
  border-color: #aed248 !important;
}

#joinus .list-group-item.active,
.list-group-item.active:hover {
  background-color: #adce1b !important;
  border-color: #adce1b !important;
}
#whyptcl .list-group-item.active,
.list-group-item.active:hover {
  background-color: #adce1b !important;
  border-color: #adce1b !important;
}
.panel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<body onload="get_current_page()">
  <div id="MainMenu">
    <div class="list-group panel">
      <a
        id="whylist"
        href="#why"
        class="list-group-item"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-parent="#MainMenu"
        >Menu 1</a
      >
      <div class="collapse" id="why">
        <a
          id="values"
          href="values.html"
          onclick="activate(this)"
          class="list-group-item"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-parent="#SubMenu1"
          >Menu 1 a</a
        >
        <a
          id="ambassadors"
          href="ambassadors.html"
          onclick="activate(this)"
          class="list-group-item"
          >Menu 1 b</a
        >
        <a
          id="documentary"
          href="documentary.html"
          onclick="activate(this)"
          class="list-group-item"
          >Menu 1 c</a
        >
      </div>
      <a
        id="joinuslist"
        href="#joinus"
        class="list-group-item"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-parent="#MainMenu"
        >Menu 2</a
      >
      <div class="collapse" id="joinus">
        <a
          id="my-profile"
          href="my-profile.html"
          onclick="activate(this)"
          class="list-group-item"
          >Menu 2 a</a
        >
        <a
          id="students"
          href="students.html"
          onclick="activate(this)"
          class="list-group-item"
          >Menu 2 b</a
        >
        <a
          id="forecast-career"
          href="forecast-career.html"
          onclick="activate(this)"
          class="list-group-item"
          >Menu 2 c</a
        >
        <a
          id="faqs"
          href="faqs.html"
          onclick="activate(this)"
          class="list-group-item"
          >Menu 2 e</a
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't know why bootstrap isn't doing it, but here's some jQuery on a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltp9qLox/6/) for you. The alert is displaying the `href` that is active.

Is that what you're after?

---

**Update - 09/01/2022**

Edited the old fiddle, here's the new one http://jsfiddle.net/dh7t3cbp/1/

```
$('.list-group').on('click', '> a', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $('.list-group').find('.active').removeClass('active');
  $this.addClass('active');

  alert($this.attr('href') + ' is active');
});

$('.list-group .collapse').on('click', '> a', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this),
    $parent = $this.parent('.collapse');
  $parent.find('.active').removeClass('active');
  $this.addClass('active');

  alert($this.attr('href') + ' is active');
});

.list-group panel.active, .list-group panel.active a.active {
  background-color: #030;
  border-color: #aed248;
}
```

Comment: The background only changes for `menu` not their `sub-menu`

Comment: sorry - i thought "list-item" was the main list. you could just add `.active a.list-group-item { background-color: #HEX; }` to your CSS

Answer (score 3):

Add the following css in your code as :

```
.list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"]{
     background-color: black !important;
  border-color: #aed248;

}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lgxzjbk/1/)**

Comment: The background only changes for `menu` not their `sub-menu`

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple but maybe not obvious.
You can pass `this` (the clicked element) to an `onclick` event handler and then set the `active` class on the selected menu.

```
var activate = function(el) {    
    var current = document.querySelector('.active');
    if (current) {
        current.classList.remove('active');
    }
    el.classList.add('active');
}
```

I created this Fiddle to answer your question

http://jsfiddle.net/Ltp9qLox/9/

The script can be greatly improved, this is just an example. I'm not aware of any non-JS way to achieve the same result.

You can also store the old activated element so you don't have to use query selector every time, in this way the script would be

```
var current;
var activate = function(el) {    
    if (current) {
        current.classList.remove('active');
    }
    current = el;
    el.classList.add('active');
}
```

Bu then you have to initialize `current`with the value of the starting element.

**Adding Persistency**

Of course any change to the style of an element can't survive after a refresh without implementing some kind of persistency that is something completely different than the simple implementation. Keep in mind that there are hundreds of different ways to achieve this, one of which is [NOT refreshing at all the page](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/).

Anyway if you prefer the quick and dirt way then [using localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) is probably the best solution. This is a simple implementation

```
var currentHref = localStorage.getItem("currentSelected");
var current = currentHref ? document.querySelector('[href="'+currentHref+'"]') : null;
function activate(el) {    
    if (current && current !== el) {
        current.classList.remove('active');
    }
    current = el;
    current.classList.add('active');
    localStorage.setItem("currentSelected", current.getAttribute('href'));
}
```

Basically you save something that you can use to recognize the element that was selected, in this case i used the `href` attribute value because in our case that is unique, but you could also assign id or other attributes to the elements and use that.
Then on load i read the localStorage to retrieve the saved `href` and if found i get the element inside the page using a simple [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Just remember that copy-pasting this kind of solution doesnt help you building better websites, you should read articles on the internet and implement what solution is best for your own use case.

Comment: How would I store, because when i click on the any link and page refreshes then it didn't save the previous states?

Comment: @MTaqi i added the persistency section to the answer. If you feel this answers your question please remember to accept the answer otherwise the question will stay open.

Answer (score 0):

Just to change the active item background color, (I've changed to grey from default - blue) add this to your css:

```
.list-group-item.active {
background-color: grey;
border-color: grey; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add these Bootstrap classes;

```
.list-group-item-dark
.list-group-item-success
.list-group-item-warning
.list-group-item-primary
.list-group-item-danger
.list-group-item-secondary
.list-group-item-info
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).